# My python script runs through my IDE (PyCharm) but it won't run using the Python shell

Tags: python, logging, pycharm

I have a short python script that uses the logging module and the configparser module.
I use PyCharm 2.7.1 and Python 3.3 under Win7.

When I run my script using PyCharm - it works. This is the output from the PyCharm console:

```
C:\Python33\python.exe C:/some/path/script.py

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I run the same command in the cmd and this is what I get:

```
C:\>C:\Python33\python.exe C:/some/path/script.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/some/path/script.py", line 10
1, in <module>
initLogger()
File "C:/some/path/script.py", line 97, in initLogger
logging.config.fileConfig('RecorderMoverLog.config.ini')
File "C:\Python33\lib\logging\config.py", line 70, in fileConfig
formatters = _create_formatters(cp)
File "C:\Python33\lib\logging\config.py", line 103, in _create_formatters
flist = cp["formatters"]["keys"]
File "C:\Python33\lib\configparser.py", line 942, in __getitem__
raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'formatters'
```

Why does it run in PyCharm and won't run under python shell?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is most likely because of your `PYTHON_PATH`. List `sys.path` in your Python IDE and in your Python in shell. Look for the difference in the Python libraries.

Comment: It used to be `sys.path` in python2.x. Has it changed to `os.path` in 3.x?

Comment: Or simply because of wrong `pwd` (current working directory).

Comment: I don't think it was change. My mistake. Sorry.

Comment: `os.path` is a module containing various path functions.

Comment: sys.path in pycharm:
    ['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\JetBrains\\PyCharm 2.7.1\\helpers\\pydev',
 'C:\\Python33\\lib\\site-packages\\distribute-0.6.27-py3.3.egg',
 'C:\\Python33\\lib\\site-packages\\pip-1.1-py3.3.egg',
 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python33.zip',
 'C:\\Python33\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python33\\lib',
 'C:\\Python33',
 'C:\\Python33\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Python33\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-0.6c11-py3.3.egg-info',
 'C:\\some/path']

Comment: in python shell:
    
['',
 'C:\\Python33\\lib\\site-packages\\distribute-0.6.27-py3.3.egg',
 'C:\\Python33\\lib\\site-packages\\pip-1.1-py3.3.egg',
 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python33.zip',
 'C:\\Python33\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python33\\lib',
 'C:\\Python33',
 'C:\\Python33\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Python33\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-0.6c11-py3.3.egg-info']

Comment: Thank you both. What I needed to do is to run the cmd from the project directory... thanks!